# How to get the previous index of an array (ring buffer way) in a clean way?

Tags: arrays, language-agnostic

Having an array:

```
array = [1, 3, 5, 78]
```

And treating it as a ring buffer (last element is connected with first element).

Getting the next element of any element is easy [*]:

```
element = 3
index = array.findIndex( e => e == 3)
nextIndex = (index + 1) % array.length // This line!
```

This works in case `element` is not found: `index == -1`.
This works in case `element` is the last index: `index == 3`.
This works in case `element` is found and is not the last index.

But if I want to find the *previousIndex*, I don't see any way that write separate code for the 3 different conditions:

- the `element` is not found
- the `element` is the first element
- the `element` is found and is not the first element

Is there a one-line magic code that gives me the previousIndex in a clean and direct way?

[*] Pseudo code in JS but it can be any language

Comment: You seem to be implicitly treating the array as a ring buffer, which is not how arrays are often treated? When you say previous index you mean looping back to the end of the array if currently at zero?

Comment: `(array.reverse().find( e => e == 3) + 1) % index.length`?

Comment: Yes @GSerg , I am treating the array as a ring buffer. Thanks!

Comment: You mean `array.length`? Also in JS it's `findIndex`, `find` gives you the element not the index (and you can use [`.at`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at), but would have to special-case `-1`).

Comment: Yes @jonrsharpe thanks, typos corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `nextIndex` in case of the element not being found only works, because you are exploiting a language specific property, ie `findIndex` will return `-1` in case an element is not found. This may not be the case in other languages, thus your approach is not language agnostic because you may need a special case handling for  the "not found case" in other languages.

I personally find it much easier to read, understand and maintain, if special cases (ie the element is not found) are explicitly treated, rather than exploiting some (maybe language specific) behaviour ...

Keeping that in mind, you can easily find the `previousIndex` of any element contained in the array, by adding `array.length - 1` to its index before doing the `% array.length`.

The additional `array.length` won't change the result if `index > 0` (because 1 % 4 === 5 % 4 === 9 % 4 === ... === 1). But it will shift the resulting `-1` for the `index = 0` to be positive and thus yield an index pointing to the last element in the array (because `-1 + array.length` obviously is the same as `array.length - 1`)

See also the following snippet (I replaced the elements in the array with letters, to reduce possible confusion in the output)

```js
let 
  array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
  search = [...array, "e"];  //add another element to search for to simulate the "not found" case


for (let s of search) {
  let 
    index = array.findIndex(e => e == s),
    found = index >= 0, //or whatever findIndex may return on a non-existing element in different languages
    nextIndex = found ? (index + 1) % array.length : 0,
    previousIndex = found ? (index - 1 + array.length) % array.length : 0
    
  console.log("element", s, "   found at", index, "   next", nextIndex, "   previous", previousIndex);
}
```

And not even that approach is language agnostic, because it relies on array-indexes to start with `0`, but there are languages, that start their arrays at index `1`

Comment: Great one! thanks for the detailed analysis